# what't the meaning of mongo $minKey?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

this page :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

```
{ "date": new Date(1393804800000), "grade": MaxKey(), "score": 2 },
```

when i show Maxkey() in  mongo shell:

```
MaxKey().help
The MaxKey BSON Class.
For more information on usage: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MaxKey.html
```

how can I understand it ?
should I compare it with "$lt"  or "$gt" like this ?

```
db.test.find({"grades.grade": {"$gt":"a"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

MinKey and MaxKey are MongoDB internal types.  Their purpose is to represent the theoretical extremes.

MinKey is less than any value, and MaxKey is greater than any value, regardless of type.

See [Comparison/Sort Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/)

Answer (score 0):

I think `minKey()` or `maxKey()` is just a special value which can only be queried by `{ $type : "maxKey" }`

If data is below,

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : { "$maxKey" : 1 },
            "score" : 2
        },        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-01-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : { "$maxKey" : 1 },
            "score" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Use,

```
db.test.find({"grades.grade": {"$gt":"A"}})
```

Will return nothing.

---

But if use,

```
db.test.find({"grades.grade" : { $type : "maxKey" }})
```

Will return,

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : { "$maxKey" : 1 },
            "score" : 2
        },        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-01-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : { "$maxKey" : 1 },
            "score" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```